# I'm confused how I send data to my AJAX form from my flask python api

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

```
@app.route("/therapist", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def therapist():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userText = request.args.get('msg')
        chat_response = chat(userText)
        return getResponse == chat_response
    return render_template("therapist.html")
```

```
<div id="userInput">
              <input id="textInput" class="form-control" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Talk to me!">
              <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script>
    function getResponse() {
        let userText = $("#textInput").val();
        let userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + userText + '</span></p>';
        $("#textInput").val("");
        $("#chatbox").append(userHtml);
        document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
        $.get("/get", { msg: userText }).done(function(data) {
        var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + '</span></p>';
        $("#chatbox").append(botHtml);
        document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
});
}
    $("#textInput").keypress(function(e) {
    //if enter key is pressed
        if(e.which == 13) {
            getResponse();
        }
    });
    $("#buttonInput").click(function() {
        getResponse();
```

I have python code that trained a chatbot imported into my main.py file. I want to call the chat function on the user input from my website, and then send back the chatbot response to the website in the ajax form. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: You are making a request to `/get`, when the route on your function is clearly `/therapist`.

Comment: can't you make a get request on a specific webpage?

Comment: Basically I want to call my python chat() on "msg" data and then have the response of the chat() be set to the botHTML var in ajax and then send that data back to the webpage

Comment: Yes, but you are making a "get" request to the url `/get`.  That's the problem.  Your function `therapist` expects to be called (through the route) as `/therapist`.  You need to fix the URL in your `$.get` call.

Comment: So then how would I do this get request on the therapist page? That's where the form is located. Do I need to have another function on the same page?

Comment: Okay I got it now, thank you! I'm having an issue with sending the data from the webform, should I be using a post request instead?